# IdentityServer4 as Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm newbie in IdentityServer4. Now I try to realize microservices with JWT-authorization (by passing tokens each request to the API). So, the schema is primitive - IDS4 server as an auth server, ASP.NET Identity + MSSQL for client data usage and storage, other services use auth service for token validation.
So, I've looked many articles, but found none of example, where I can customize IDS4 behavior.
For example, I want client to call `AuthorizeByLogin(AuthorizeView model)` API method, realized in the IDS4 project, where model is an object of 2 fields: `Username, Password`. In this method I want to check user in the Database and generate access_token, which is passed to the client for working with protected API. 
But there is nowhere an example how to do this (call API method, pass the object and receive token). Most of it says "use */connect/token for this".

Could anyone give me an example of code in which this way is realized well? Or maybe tell me which interfaces I should implement and correctly pass to the services in ASP.NET Core app for Authentication Web API + IdentityServer4 realization?

Thank you.

Comment: how did you solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a plethora of quickstart examples in the [Identity Server 4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/community.html). Also from what I understand, you are wanting to use `ResourceOwnerCredentials` grant type. You won't be able to easily modify the endpoints that issue the tokens without reimplementing majority of Identity Server 4 but you can implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` interface and setup a client with an appropriate allowed grant type:

```
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "your_client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("your_password".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedScopes = { ... }
    }
```

After that, the clients can call `connect\token` endpoint by providing user name and password of a given user alongside their own credentials:

```
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    UserName = "alice",
    Password = "password",
    Scope = "api1"
});
```

Comment: Thank you! If I'm not mistaken, It's not possible to create API for authenticate users internally in IdentityServer4, is it? I can't make some different Authenticate methods like, for example, AuthenticateByPhone, AuthenticateByEmail with json input data passing which I could generate token for client usage accessing other protected Web APIs? And I also can't customize given token validation, can me?  Maybe you know, Is there any Identity Server analogs which could be well-customized and allow me to create SOA with separate identity server based on ASP.NET Core Identity with own API?

Comment: No problems. What you are trying to do is not gonna be possible easily because you are trying to create your own grant types and authentication flows essentially. Token validation is customizable though, but it highly depends on what api resource type you are using. Lastly, you probably might want to look into OpenIdDict (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) allthough i am not sure if that will be much customizable either in regards to custom flows.

Comment: link to github quickstarts is broken

Comment: @anatol Thanks, I updated the link to the official docs one. Looks like the combined samples repo has been removed though.